# Изменить путь в 'хлебных крошках'

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Проблема с 'хлебными крошками' в WordPress. Есть страница, на которой выводятся статьи. При переходе на любую статью 'хлебные крошки' выглядят следующим образом 'Главная/Категория/Статья', а нужно 'Главная/страница на которой выводятся записи/Статья'. Можно ли это как-то реализовать или если да, то как? Заранее благодарю.

```
    function dimox_breadcrumbs() {

  /* === ОПЦИИ === */
  $text['home'] = 'Главная'; // текст ссылки "Главная"
  $text['category'] = '%s'; // текст для страницы рубрики
  $text['search'] = 'Результаты поиска по запросу "%s"'; // текст для страницы с результатами поиска
  $text['tag'] = 'Записи с тегом "%s"'; // текст для страницы тега
  $text['author'] = 'Статьи автора %s'; // текст для страницы автора
  $text['404'] = 'Ошибка 404'; // текст для страницы 404
  $text['page'] = 'Страница %s'; // текст 'Страница N'
  $text['cpage'] = 'Страница комментариев %s'; // текст 'Страница комментариев N'

  $wrap_before = '<div class="breadcrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">'; // открывающий тег обертки
  $wrap_after = '</div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->'; // закрывающий тег обертки
  $sep = '›'; // разделитель между "крошками"
  $sep_before = '<span class="sep">'; // тег перед разделителем
  $sep_after = '</span>'; // тег после разделителя
  $show_home_link = 1; // 1 - показывать ссылку "Главная", 0 - не показывать
  $show_on_home = 0; // 1 - показывать "хлебные крошки" на главной странице, 0 - не показывать
  $show_current = 1; // 1 - показывать название текущей страницы, 0 - не показывать
  $before = '<span class="current">'; // тег перед текущей "крошкой"
  $after = '</span>'; // тег после текущей "крошки"
  /* === КОНЕЦ ОПЦИЙ === */

  global $post;
  $home_url = home_url('/');
  $link_before = '<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
  $link_after = '</span>';
  $link_attr = ' itemprop="item"';
  $link_in_before = '<span itemprop="name">';
  $link_in_after = '</span>';
  $link = $link_before . '<a href="%1$s"' . $link_attr . '>' . $link_in_before . '%2$s' . $link_in_after . '</a>' . $link_after;
  $frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');
  $parent_id = ($post) ? $post->post_parent : '';
  $sep = ' ' . $sep_before . $sep . $sep_after . ' ';
  $home_link = $link_before . '<a href="' . $home_url . '"' . $link_attr . ' class="home">' . $link_in_before . $text['home'] . $link_in_after . '</a>' . $link_after;

  if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    if ($show_on_home) echo $wrap_before . $home_link . $wrap_after;

  } else {

    echo $wrap_before;
    if ($show_home_link) echo $home_link;

    if ( is_category() ) {
      $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
      if ($cat->parent != 0) {
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat->parent, TRUE, $sep);
        $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
        $cats = preg_replace('#<a href="http://main-domain.ml/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8/"><\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo $cats;
      }
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $cat = $cat->cat_ID;
        echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_category_link($cat), get_cat_name($cat)) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
      } else {
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['category'], single_cat_title('', false)) . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      if (have_posts()) {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
      } else {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $sep;
      echo sprintf($link, get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m')), get_the_time('F'));
      if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y'));
      if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
      if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        printf($link, $home_url . $slug['slug'] . '/', $post_type->labels->singular_name);
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
        if (!$show_current || get_query_var('cpage')) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
        $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
        echo $cats;
        if ( get_query_var('cpage') ) {
          echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_permalink(), get_the_title()) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['cpage'], get_query_var('cpage')) . $after;
        } else {
          if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        }
      }

    // custom post type
    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_post_type_archive_link($post_type->name), $post_type->label) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
      } else {
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . $post_type->label . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      $parent = get_post($parent_id);
      $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
      if ($cat) {
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
        $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
        echo $cats;
      }
      printf($link, get_permalink($parent), $parent->post_title);
      if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$parent_id ) {
      if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
        $breadcrumbs = array();
        while ($parent_id) {
          $page = get_page($parent_id);
          if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
            $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID));
          }
          $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
        }
        $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
          echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
          if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $sep;
        }
      }
      if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $tag_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $tag = get_tag($tag_id);
        echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_tag_link($tag_id), $tag->name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
      } else {
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['tag'], single_tag_title('', false)) . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
      global $author;
      $author = get_userdata($author);
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_author_posts_url($author->ID), $author->display_name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
      } else {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $author->display_name) . $after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
      if ($show_current) echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;

    } elseif ( has_post_format() && !is_singular() ) {
      if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
      echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

  }
} // end of dimox_breadcrumbs()
```

Comment: Все можно. Надо прааить код хлебных крошек. Вариантов их создания миллион, поэтому покажите ваш код, который выводит хлебные крошки.

Comment: добавил код.как я понял это нужно менять на этапе формирования ссылок,но как это сделать не знаю